# I want to return a sql column conditionally only if there is not a value in the other column

Tags: sql

I want to write a query that will return the Id and a single ECU value (if the override exists(ECUOverride) use the override, otherwise use the ECU). I want the value that will come from the ECU or ECUOverride in an alias column.

The table is below:

```
Id  ProjectNumber   ERU ERUOverride Acres   Category
101854  943 17.55   17.55   4.79    Non-Residential
101855  943 0.50    0.00    0.12    Residential
101856  943 0.33    0.33    0.27    Residential
101857  943 10.40   10.40   2.89    Non-Residential
101858  943 0.50    0.00    0.11    Residential
101859  943 18.85   18.85   5.00    Non-Residential
101860  943 0.65    0.65    0.47    Residential
101861  943 0.98    0.98    0.66    Residential
101862  943 0.50    0.00    0.24    Residential
101863  943 0.50    0.00    0.08    Residential
101864  943 0.25    0.00    0.29    Residential
```

Any help on this would be great

Comment: read about `case ...  when .. else`

Comment: I've used those but don't know how to combine them with aliases and with two different column values

Comment: can you show what you have tried? Also the expected result?

Comment: This is what I have so far: SELECT 
Id,
CASE ERUOverride WHEN ERUOverride != 0.00 THEN ERUOverride
ELSE ERU AS ERUVALUE end
 FROM projects;

Comment: What database are you using?  Is `0.00` not a valid value?  I would expect a non-existent value to use `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query like this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN ECUOverride <> 0 THEN ECUOverride
    ELSE ECU 
    END AS ECUValue
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your logic as:

```
select (case ERUOverride when 0.00 then ERU else ERUOverride end) 
from projects
```

Comment: Awesome that works. IF I wanted to get the sum I would do?: select SUM(case ERUOverride when 0.00 then ERU else ERUOverride end) 
from projects

Comment: @SJW525 . . . Yes, you can nest `case` expressions in aggregation functions.